dj_rest_auth SocialLoginView error "Failed to exchange code for access token"
I have configured social login with Google with dj-rest-auth and Django rest framework. When I try to pass the authentication code to my endpoint, I get a 400 error:
Request
{
    "code": "4%google-auth-code"
}

Response
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Failed to exchange code for access token"
    ]
}

Here is my code. settings.py file:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    ...

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...

    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
]

SITE_ID = 1
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'my_social_key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'google_secret'
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY,
            'secret': SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET,
        },
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

user/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from user import views

app_name = 'user'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('auth/google/', views.GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login'),
    ...
]

user/views.py
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/google/'
    client_class = OAuth2Client

**requirements.txt
**
dj-rest-auth==6.0.0django-allauth==0.61.0   

Google Cloud Console is working properly. Redirect url is also fine
enter image description here
I tried to catch this error from the module dj-rest-auth, but even there the information is superficial:
`Error retrieving access token: b'{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Malformed auth code."\n}'` 


A few things need to be considered:

You need to pass the access token in form-data; if passed in raw
form, it returns an error.
The key name must be access_token.
Ensure that the token is generated with the email and profile
scopes.

I assume you are exchanging the token for access and refresh tokens in the Google Auth Playground.
